# Como atribuir value do ComboBox para variável?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou customizando a parte de registro de usuário, utilizando a ferramenta Identity do Entity Framework.

Então na pagina de registro, adicionei um `ComboBox` (Select em HTML):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parte da minha View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Departamento, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">           
        <select class="form-control" id="select">
            <option>Administração</option>
            <option>Produção</option>
            <option>Vendas</option>
            <option>Comercial</option>
            <option>Compras</option>
            <option>Qualidade SGQ</option>
            <option>Qualidade Inspeção</option>
            <option>Engenharia</option>
            <option>Serviços</option>
            <option>Desenvolvimento</option>
            <option>Marketing</option>
            <option>T.I</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

E defini o campo "Departamento" como requerido (obrigatório):

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    public string Usuario { get; set;}

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Sobrenome")]
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
    public string Departamento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Porém, ao tentar realizar o cadastro do novo usuário, mesmo eu selecionando o departamento é como se estivesse em branco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou preencher a propriedade `value` da tag `<option>`:

```
<select id="dropdowntipo">
   <option value="Exemplo1">Exemplo1</option>
   <option value="Exemplo2">Exemplo2</option>
   <option value="Exemplo3">Exemplo3</option>
</select>
```

Como já está utilizando `Razor` pode utilizar o `@Html.DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Tipo, new List<SelectListItem>
{
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo1", Value="Exemplo1"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo2", Value="Exemplo2"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Exemplo3", Value="Exemplo3"}
})
```

Comment: Amigo, qual a diferença entre os dois?

Comment: Nenhuma pois o código que será enviado para o navegador será o mesmo, a questão é seguir o padrão, neste caso ele está desenvolvendo com o `Razor` as demais tags, então na minha opinião melhor continuar seguindo rs.